# What is wrong in this FULL OUTER JOIN with sub queries?

Tags: mysql, full-outer-join

```
SELECT * 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT * 
         FROM tb_emp_activity_details
            , tb_activity_types
        WHERE act_type_related_id = activity_type_id 
          AND emp_act_org_id = 1 
          AND emp_related_id = 1
     ) tabone 
  FULL 
 OUTER 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT * 
         FROM tb_emp_effort_details
            , tb_effort_types  
        WHERE eff_type_related_id = effort_type_id 
          AND emp_eff_org_id = 1 
          AND emp_related_id = 1
     ) tabtwo 
    ON tabone.startDate = tabtwo.startDate 
 ORDER 
    BY tabone.startDate
     , tabtwo.startDate;
```

Can some one point out what am i doing wrong in this query? It ways says to check SQL syntax near FULL OUTER JOIN.

Thanks.

Comment: `FULL OUTER JOIN` is not available AFAIK in MySQL

Comment: That was easy. Next.